# Is there any difference in function between these two Angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn Angular and I have come across many different examples of people formatting their controllers in these ways. Is there a difference in function?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
}]);
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

Comment: There is a slight but very important difference when minifying your code. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality will seem the same at first, but the first bit of code is utilizing dependency injection!

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

In short, by including the "['$scope'," you are ensuring that angular will be able to resolve the correct dependency when the controller function asks for it.

I myself prefer to use the method of manual injection listed in John Papa's angular style guide, it makes a lot more sense to me (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection)

NameOfController.$inject = ['$scope'];